# Equivalent definitions of "Homeomorphisms"

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, solution-verification

I found that the equivalent definition of a homeomorphism is as follows:

Let X and Y be two topological spaces. A map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be homeomorphism if $f$ is bijective and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Now I found a equivalent definition of a homeomorphism which is as follows: $U$ is open in $X$ iff $f(U)$ is open in $Y$.

I got stuck to prove the above.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

Consider $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous. Since $f(U)$ is is open in $Y$, by the definition of continuity $f^{-1}(f(U))$ is open in X. Now since $f, f^{-1}$ are bijection, then $f^{-1}(f(U)) = U$ (in general,  $U$ is a subset of $f^{-1}(f(U))$, and equality holds if $f$ is a injective map (bijective, in particular)). Thus, $U$ is open in $X$.

Now we will have to prove $U$ is open in $X$, then $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. I have an idea that for this we should take the map $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$. Now if $U$ is open in $X$, then by the definition of continuity we have $(f^{-1}) ^{-1} (U)$ is open in $Y$.

Does $(f^{-1}) ^{-1} (U)$ mean $f(U)$?

Now  I have now idea. Please help me.

Comment: Yes, $(f^{-1}) ^{-1} (U) =f(U)$. Prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kavi Rama Murthy already said in the comments, yes $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=f(U)$. I will give you a simple hint on how to prove it. By definition:
$$(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=\{y\in Y : f^{-1}(y)\in U\}$$
And finally $f^{-1}(y)\in U \iff y=f(x)$ for $x\in U$ (again, by definition). I think you can prove the rest.

However, note that your proof is not complete if you stop here, since you want to prove that those are **equivalent** definitions for homeomorphism. You have just proved the following:
$$[f\colon X\to Y\ \text{is a homeomorphism}] \implies [U \text{ is open in } X \iff f(U) \text{ is open in } Y]$$
Now, you would have to prove that the converse is also true. As an important remark (you didn't state this clearly), the *bijectivity* of $f$ *has to be assumed in both directions*, i.e., the two statements are equivalent when previously assuming that $f$ is a bijection. That means that you have to prove that:
$$[f:X\to Y \text{ is bijective and }U \text{ is open in } X \iff f(U) \text{ is open in } Y]\implies[f\colon X\to Y\ \text{is a homeomorphism}]$$
I will leave this proof up to you, since you already have all the tools you need. If you get stuck, don't hesitate to write a comment.

Comment: Here, I am  writing the proof which you left for me. Assume that $U$ is open in $X$ $\iff$ $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. We have already given that $f$ is a bijective map. First we will prove $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous. Let $U$ is open in $X$, then $(f^{-1}) ^{-1} (U) = f(U)$ is open in $Y$.  Now we will prove that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.  Let $V$ is open in $Y$. We will prove that $f^{-1} (V)$ is open in $X$. Since  $f$ is bijective, we have $U$ subset of $X$ such that $f(U) =V$. So, $f(U)$ is open in $Y$, $U = f^{-1} (V)$ is open in $X$. Is it correct?

Comment: Also, you wrote that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=\{y\in Y : f^{-1}(y)\in U\}$. Can we write that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=\{y\in Y : f^{-1}(y)\in U\} = \{y\in Y : y\in f(U)\} = f(U)$?

Comment: @user454229 Yes, everything you commented is correct. Simply note that, for the equality $\{y\in Y: f^{-1}(y)\in U\} = \{y\in Y: y\in f(U)\}$ you have to make use of the fact that I gave you, namely, that $f^{-1}(y)\in U\iff y=f(x)$ for $x\in U$. Congratulations.